# Does go get command do cache?

Tags: go, go-get

I trying to find if the `go get` command do cache or not but I don't find any information inside https://golang.org/cmd/go/.

I think there is no cache but I'm not sure.

Does `go get` do cache and if yes where is located ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`go get` downloads the packages named by the import paths, along with their
dependencies.

Then installs the package, using `go install`, which uses `go build` and `go build` caches recent build results in `$GOPATH/pkg`

The default location for cache data is a subdirectory named `go-build` in the standard user cache directory for the current operating system.

Cache directory:

`go env GOCACHE`

For more information about cache `go help cache`

More information about caching, [1.10](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#build), [documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Build_and_test_caching), [upcoming changes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.11#gocache)